# How to initialize an array in Julia when you don't know their dimensions in first place

Tags: julia

I am trying to compute the Fibonacci sequence until a term less than `4*10^6`. How can I define the dimensions of the `f` array when I don't know at first when to stop? In this case, I defined by trial and error `f = [1:32;]`.

```
k = 32
f = [1:k;]
for i in 1:k
    if i < 3
        f[i] = i
    elseif f[i] < 4*10^6
        f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2]
    else
        break
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to define it upfront.

Just use `push!`:

```
f = [1, 2]
while true
    fi = f[end] + f[end-1]
    fi < 4*10^6 ? push!(f, fi) : break
end
```

Side note: in case of Fibonacci sequence it is relatively easy to calculate `k` using the formula given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) in *Computation by rounding* section. Also normally you define `f[2]` to be equal to `1` and not to `2` as in your question.